typescript - cannot pass a function parameters with the same type of its parameters
Here is a basic version that demonstrates the issue. Does anyone know why I cannot pass the return value to the wrapped function? The javascript works but typescript is not allowing it.
// accept a function with unknown parameters and return a function that takes in those same paramters
const wrapFunc =
  <T extends (...args: never[]) => Promise<unknown>>(f: T): ((...args: Parameters<T>) => void) =>
  (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
    f(...args)
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }

// a simple promise returning whatever string is given to it
const promise = async (word: string) => word

wrapFunc(promise)('works!')

// this accepts a promise that is the same type that wrapFunc does and gives the promise to wrapFunc
// it also accepts a function that returns the same type of parameter that the promise takes and passes
// the return value from the second function to the wrapped version of the first
const passThrough = <
  T extends (...args: never[]) => Promise<unknown>,
  U extends () => Parameters<T>,
>(
  f: T,
  paramsGenerator: U,
) => {
  const wrapped = wrapFunc(f)
  wrapped(paramsGenerator())
}

passThrough(promise, () => 'this works when ran but fails compilation!')

  

Output
"use strict";
// accept a function with unknown parameters and return a function that takes in those same paramters
const wrapFunc = (f) => (...args) => {
    f(...args)
        .then((result) => console.log(result))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
// a simple promise returning whatever string is given to it
const promise = async (word) => word;
wrapFunc(promise)('works!');
// this accepts a promise that is the same type that wrapFunc does and gives the promise to wrapFunc
// it also accepts a function that returns the same type of parameter that the promise takes and passes
// the return value from the second function to the wrapped version of the first
const passThrough = (f, paramsGenerator) => {
    const wrapped = wrapFunc(f);
    wrapped(paramsGenerator());
};
passThrough(promise, () => 'this works when ran but fails compilation!');


Compiler Options
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}

Playground Link: Provided
Ideally I wouldn't have to change the parameter to a single type and could accept a variadic amount of parameters as long as the other function matched those parameters.
So using this works but isn't ideal to accept any function:
type Parameter<T extends (args: unknown) => unknown> = T extends (arg: infer P) => unknown ? P : never


You've written passThrough so the wrapped function cannot be variadic... If that's not what you want, why did you write it that way?

(see prev comment).  Take a look at this playground link, which shows how I'd write this. Do either of passThroughSingle or passThroughVariadic meet your needs? If so I can write up either or both as an answer. If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz thanks for the quick response! The use case is we pass an api promise to a hook that abstracts the promise and then I want to pass that function through a high up component along with a function that can map state to parameters. So it would be nice to have it be able to hand something like (id, paramatersObject) => void as well as (parametersObject) => void but I guess the issue is that I have a return type set to variadic. Maybe a check can be done to see if it is single argument or not?

But either paramsGenerator() returns an array or it doesn't. And you want a runtime check to see if a function expects a single argument or not? You could check the length property of the function but that's really fragile. Just pick passThroughSingle or passThroughVariadic. What's wrong with passThrowVariadic where paramsGenerator returns a one-element array?  How should we proceed here?

Yeah the array is fine it just looks a bit weird when it's a single argument being returned especially when the wrapped function accepts a single argument with no problem but only has a problem when accepting a single argument that is a result of the params generator

So how shall we proceed with an answer? I mean, how do you plan to tell the difference between a function that accepts a single array argument and one that accepts multiple arguments? I think you'd be much better off doing something consistent, even if it's "weird" for single arguments, rather than try to make your program figure out the intent of the function passed in by inspecting it. So, would that be an acceptable answer? I'm happy to write one up.

Yeah but would you be able to also explain why this doesn't work https://shorturl.at/YzYgI

Because Parameters<T> is a conditional type that depends on a generic type parameter, and TypeScript just defers evaluation of those. It doesn't "understand" what Parameters means. That's why I rewrote the types to be just generics and no conditional types. But this feels like scope creep. Is that something you need explained in your original question? Or just a followup question? If it's the former then you should [edit] the question to ask it (and make sure you're asking only a single question). If it's the latter then we should put that aside and focus on the current question.

You defined your paramsGenerator as a () => Parameters<T>, which is correct, but bear in mind that arguments of a function represented by Parameters<T> is an array. So you cannot pass an array of arguments to a function, that expects a few arguments. Just like you would try to call array.splice with .splice([1, 2, 'abc']) // one arg instead of .splice(1, 2, 'abc') // three args.
You need to spread the parameters while calling your function:
wrapped(...paramsGenerator());

And call your passThrough by providing a paramsGenerator that returns an array of parameters (as declared using () => Parameters<T>):
passThrough(promise, () => ['this works when ran but fails compilation!'])

Of course it still works with whatever arguments you use to define your original promise function. Typescript still validates them correctly in both wrapFunc and passThrough.
For reference, here is the updated Playground code, with additional function (promise2) with more arguments, including optional.

If it's an issue with parameters passed to a function then why doesn't this work? https://shorturl.at/YzYgI

Because you switched from extending highest generic function arguments ...args: never[] to extending function that take string and number. And type of passed t is not that function, it's a type T that extend that function. Notice that you can call passThrough(async (word: string) => word); and it stil works, but parameters is just [string]. That's because async (word: string) => word does extend your type T. Define passThrough without extend as const passThrough = (f: (word: string, num: number) => Promise<unknown>) and you will see it is also valid then.
